# Best-Practice for implementing UI-Fragments into HTML in VB.NET Web Forms Website

Tags: .net, vb.net, rest, webforms

I've got a legacy website that uses VB.NET 4.7.1 with the Web Forms template. I've recently been asked to implement functionality from a third party API into the website. This is the first time the website has ever consumed an API, there were no previous instances of HttpClient/WebRequest being used.

There are two primary requirements:

1. I have to authenticate the API through a keycloak token. This is being done by a GET request to get an access token that I can pass to the other APIs.
2. I have to make a combination of GET and POST requests to the API in order to build the UI-fragments that I have been asked to use.

I've found a few "Work-arounds" that allow me to do this. However, Web Forms is clearly not built to have the client-side consume Server-Side API's for DOM manipulation. I am new to the technology, so I'm looking for the best practice on how to handle this. Currently I can only get it to work by grabbing the token then entering it directly into the client-side javascript. That is obviously un-ideal for a production ready website.

Comment: Asking for "best practice" is likely to attract down votes/close votes as being primarily opinion-based. Can you reword it to avoid that phrase?

Answer (score 1):

> Web Forms is clearly not built to have the client-side consume Server-Side API's for DOM manipulation.

Hum, I can't really say using webforms, or even deciding to say adopt react or some other framework here is a issue. (such frameworks can be used with web forms).

I mean, you can always add a simple web method to ANY existing page, and then say make a ajax call to that code behind. In most cases, you don't need to do this in webforms, since it makes everything oh so easy and simple.

However, the "big" downside of this ease is of course that you often will suffer a lot more post-backs (round trips) then if you decided to push more features and code to the client side (Browser + JavaScript).

However, little stops you from adopting some of these newer technologies, or even say starting to use + adopt more JavaScript client side code.

I mean, let's say we wanted to load up some controls on the web page.

We could drop a button, click on the button, post-back, code behind runs, updates the controls, page travels back to client, and we have our controls filled out with some values.

However, let's say you don't want the "classic" post-back and round trip that webforms are so famous for?

So, we can have that button click run client side code, it can make a ajax call to the code behind, get the data, and update the controls.

Really, not much of a big deal if this is a web forms, or some other dev stack you are using.

So, say we want to grab a record, and fill out a few text boxes - but let's use a ajax call. (even templates from 10 years ago for webforms included jQuery, but if not, I'll assume we have jQuery available for use on this page).

So, say this markup and an ajax call:

```
        <h4>Select fighter</h4>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboFigher" runat="server" Width="300"
            DataTextField="Fighter"
            DataValueField="ID"
            onchange="mychange(this)"
            >
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />


    <div class="mybox" style="float:left;border:solid 1px">
        <div style="text-align: center; padding: 2px 10px 12px 10px">
            <h3 id="Fighter" runat="server"></h3>
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" 
                Width="180" Height="120" />
            <h4>Engine</h4>
            <asp:Label ID="EngineLabel" runat="server" Text="" />
            <h4>Description</h4>
            <asp:Label ID="DescLabel" runat="server" width="400px"
                Text="" style="text-align:left" Font-Size="Large" />
        </div>
    </div>

        <script>

            function mychange(myitem) {
                // get record from server, update
                // dom values
                var iPK = myitem.value
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "FighterOneAJ.aspx/GetFighter",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ PK : iPK}),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (rData) {
                        var F = rData.d
                        $('#Image2').attr("src", F.ImagePath)
                        $('#Fighter').text(F.Fighter)
                        $('#EngineLabel').text(F.Engine)
                        $('#DescLabel').text(F.Description)

                    },
                    failure: function (rData) {
                        alert("error " + rData.d);
                    }
                });

            }

        </script>
```

Code behind on web page:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        cboFigher.DataSource =
            MyRst("SELECT ID, Fighter FROM Fighters ORDER BY Fighter")
        cboFigher.DataBind()
        cboFigher.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select Fighter", "0"))

    End If

End Sub


<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function GetFighter(PK As String) As clsFigher

    Dim OneFigher As New clsFigher

    OneFigher.ID = PK
    Return OneFigher


End Function


Public Class clsFigher
    Public Fighter As String
    Public Engine As String
    Public Thrust As String
    Public Description As String
    Public ImagePath As String
    Private m_id As Integer

    Public Property ID As Integer
        Get
            Return m_id
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_id = value

            Dim cmdSQL As New _
                SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Fighters WHERE ID = @ID")

            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = m_id

            With MyRstP(cmdSQL).Rows(0)
                Fighter = .Item("Fighter")
                Engine = .Item("Engine")
                Thrust = .Item("Thrust")
                Description = .Item("Description")
                ImagePath = Replace(.Item("ImagePath"), "~/", "../")

            End With
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

So, in above, I pulled some data from the server side (a class), and then used jQuery to fill out a few controls on the page.

And certainly the above could do the reverse.

There are no post-backs, no round trips, and we used a jQuery ajax call and a simple web method on the page. So, we 100% ignored the traditional webforms approach here, and there not really anything I can think of that restricts, or removes your ability to use web method calls (ajax) in a webforms page.

So, you are free to toss in some JavaScript to the client side, call code behind (web method). And that web method can return a plain class to the JavaScript. (note it returned the data as JSON).

And to save a bit of keyboard here I used jQuery in the above.

Now, I think to call some external web method, you probably still better off to do this with server side code, and then perhaps toss in some client side JavaScript code.

As above shows, we certainly are able to mix both "modern" side JavaScript code, ajax calls, and also have a mix of server side code. And as above shows, even vb.net and webforms allows ajax calls to code behind, and even returning some structured data to the client side was rather easy.

I should also point out without ANY extra work, that web method example supports not only a web method call, but ALSO can be called and used as a REST end point. (and no changes to that code is required).

In fact, that web method will also support a SOAP (XML) call, but then again, who uses those?

But, despite this being webforms, that web method supports SOAP, JSON/ajax (web method call), and even supports using a REST call to the above web method. And ZERO code changes are required to the code behind to support all 3 cases.

So that web method will accept ajax, REST (end point), or SOAP as written. So even using a REST call to that web method (the end point) works here.